# Equivalent of fontenc in LuaLaTex

Tags: fonts, koma-script, fontspec, font-encodings, sans-serif

I'm writing a paper, and have recently switched to LuaLaTex. In pdfLaTex I've used

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

now how should I replace these, to maintain the same font(s)?
In example I'm trying to maintain this font-style:

[image]

Including `\usepackage{fontspec}` doesn't helps to maintain this style for chapter and section titles.

MWE in pdfLaTex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Second}
Third
\end{document}
```

What I tried, but haven't brought the correct result (in LuaLatex):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Second}
Third
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a complete, small example.

Comment: fontenc has nothing to do with chapter and section title style. Maybe you did load another font package that uses legacy fonts which do not work with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I added a MWE (a working one in pdfLaTex and a not working one in LuaLaTex), the document class I have to use is scrreprt.

Comment: Ok, I changed the screenshot. The previous screenshot was taken with a renewcommand to add that dot. The thing I'm not able to do is the font style.

Answer (score 7):

The default font families of LaTeX using `pdflatex` are Computer Modern. Computer Modern has a sans-serif font with a bold extended series with a high weight:

[image: Computer Modern Sans Serif bold extended]

In the `log` file of a corresponding example file you would find, that the Type-1 version of font file `cmssbx10.pfb` is used. This font file contains a font in encoding OT1.

Loading of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` not only changes the font encoding but also results in usage of the European Computer Modern families, because a font with another encoding is needed. The bold extended series of the sans-serif family has a lower weight:

[image: European Computer Modern Sans Serif bold extended]

In the screenshot not the original `ecsx` font has been used but the Type-1 replacement `sfsx2488.pfb` of `cm-super`.

With `lualatex` or `xelatex` an unicode-encoded font is needed. So the default font families switch to Latin Modern. Here the bold series of the sans-serif family has a weight similar to Computer Modern:

[image: Latin Modern Sans Serif bold]

If you'd have a look into the `log` file, you will find, that the OpenType font `lmsans10-bold.otf` is used.

So the different weights of the bold series of the sans-serif font used for the headings of your example is because usage of `lualatex` with TU1-encoded fonts results in usage of another font family than usage of `pdflatex` with T1-encoded fonts. If you want the same weight, you would need a series of the Latin Modern Sans Serif OpenType-font with another weight, e.g. a semi bold series. AFAIK such a font does not exist.

With KOMA-Script you *could* force `lualatex` to use the same T1 encoded legacy font for the headings used by `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{cmss}{bx}{n}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Second}
Third
\end{document}
```

[image: Forced T1 font]

However, you will be in trouble, if you would have characters with different code positions in your headings like the German sharp-s:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{cmss}{bx}{n}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Trouble with ß}
\end{document}
```

[image: Trouble with SS]

There are several other characters with similar problems, e.g. `»` or `«`. So this is nothing I would recommend!

Note 1: It is much easier to use a font with `pdflatex` that is similar to the font used with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Second}
Third
\end{document}
```

uses the Type-1 version of Latin Modern Sans Serif bold extended `lmssbx10.pfb`, that looks the same like the OpenType version.

Note 2: There are some other fonts, that also exist in a Type-1 version and an OpenType version, but AFAIK nothing with the same look or metrics as European Computer Modern.

Note 3: The difference in the weight of Computer Modern Roman, European Computer Modern Roman and Latin Modern Roman is much more moderate. So if you don't need sans serif headings you could also use `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}`.